# Angular 6.1 StaticInjectorError

Tags: angular, angular6

When I run cmd in angular ng serve, the application stops loading and I get the error below.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AuthService -> Http]: 
>         StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AuthService -> Http]: 
>           NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
>       Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AuthService -> Http]: 
>         StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AuthService -> Http]: 
>           NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
>           at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
>   (core.js:979)
>           at resolveToken (core.js:1232)

Comment: post your code for auth service

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to register your DI in module/component level. Otherwise you can see this type of error message.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthService } from 'PATH';

@NgModule({
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class YOURMODULE{
}
```

Read more about providers: https://angular.io/guide/providers

Comment: I did this in the app.module and it does not work. do I suppose to do this somewhere else.

Comment: @Sevensnake If this doesn't work, why is it accepted as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Static Injector Error normally rises when a class is defined and is not available for execution for the root module. For example you have Class A is the parent module of Class B and Class C. Class C is being accessed inside Class B but Class C is not defined as a provider inside parent, in this case this error would pop-up.

For your particular case : AuthService is the child and its not added as the provider in AuthModule.

> import { AuthService } from './Path';

and add AuthService in providers array would fix issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing Http to HttpClient as noted in the Angular Update guide
https://update.angular.io/